# Web Service not caring about Timeout property

Tags: c#, performance, web-services, multithreading, timeout

I'm using an automatically created (with wsdl.exe and the GUI-based "Add web reference" command) web service for [LyricWiki.org](http://lyricwiki.org/server.php?wsdl). However, since my internet connection is sucking lately, it's been taking *ages* to complete and is annoying me.

I'm trying to make it timeout in 2000ms by using the .Timeout property, but it still hangs. I also tried using the CallWithTimeout function from this [page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-generic-timeout), but no go. Have also tried the async versions of the commands, but I want to cancel it after the mentioned time.

```
var lw = new LyricWiki();
lw.Timeout = 1000;
LyricsResult result = lw.getSong(artistName, trackName);
// Hangs for a long time...
lyrics = result.lyrics;
lyricsURL = result.url;
```

Any suggestions? Been scouring StackOverflow for the past hour, but I haven't found a solution yet :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the timeout is specified in seconds, not milliseconds. At least that's the way it works with manually-created WCF stuff.

Comment: Tried that, still no go. I believe MSDN says it's in ms