# General purpose Try and Retry with a Timeout in C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm looking for a general purpose try and retry with a timeout in C#.  Basically, I want the following:

```
bool stopTrying = false;
DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
while (!stopTrying)
{
    try
    {
        //[Statement to Execute]
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(time).Milliseconds > 10000)
        {
            stopTrying = true;
            throw ex;
        }
    }
}
```

In the case above, I'm waiting for 10 second, but it should be a variable timeout based on a parameter.  I don't want to have to repeat this full code wherever I need to use it.  There are multiple places in my code where they isn't a timeout built into the API and I'll hit an exception if the application isn't ready for the statement to execute.  This would also avoid having to hardcode delays in my application before these satement.

**Clarification:** The statement in question could be something like an assignment.  If I use a delegate and method.Invoke, isn't the invokation scoped inside the delegate and not the original method?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Using your example, the solution is simple:

```
bool DoOrTimeout<T>(T method, TimeSpan timeout) where T : delegate // FIXME
{
    bool stopTrying = false;
    DateTime time = DateTime.Now;
    while (!stopTrying)
    {
        try
        {
            method.Invoke();
            stopTrying = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(time).Milliseconds > timeout.TotalMilliseconds)
            {
                stopTrying = true;
                throw;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just call `DoOrTimeout` with a delegate as the first parameter.

Comment: Please use `throw;` to rethrow exceptions, not `throw ex;` as the latter destroys the stack trace.

Comment: @Will, I used the OP's code.  You're right, though; `throw` should be used alone.  I'll update my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You're missing a stopTrying = true; after calling "method.Invoke()";

Comment: this code doesn't compile.  delegate can't be used as a constraint.

Comment: Comparing `Milliseconds` on one `TimeSpan` to `TotalMilliseconds` on another one must be a typo (bug). Why not just compare the `TimeSpan` directly? That type overloads usual operators. Therefore: `if (DateTime.Now - time > timeout) { ... }` is more correct.

Comment: I've done [another version of this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75932745/3873799) which fixes some of this answer's issues and provides an option to decide whether to throw or not.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the prettiest thing, but I seems to work nicely so far. And it doesn't use exceptions to indicate a timeout.

```
public static class TimeoutOperation
{
  private static readonly TimeSpan DefaultTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 10);
  private static readonly TimeSpan DefaultGranularity = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 100);

  public static ThreadResult<TResult> DoWithTimeout<TResult>(Func<TResult> action)
  {
    return DoWithTimeout<TResult>(action, DefaultTimeout);
  }

  public static ThreadResult<TResult> DoWithTimeout<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, TimeSpan timeout)
  {
    return DoWithTimeout<TResult>(action, timeout, DefaultGranularity);
  }

  public static ThreadResult<TResult> DoWithTimeout<TResult>(Func<TResult> action, TimeSpan timeout, TimeSpan granularity)
  {
    Thread thread = BuildThread<TResult>(action);
    Stopwatch stopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
    ThreadResult<TResult> result = new ThreadResult<TResult>();

    thread.Start(result);
    do
    {
      if (thread.Join(granularity) && !result.WasSuccessful)
      {
        thread = BuildThread<TResult>(action);
        thread.Start(result);
      }

    } while (stopwatch.Elapsed < timeout && !result.WasSuccessful);
    stopwatch.Stop();

    if (thread.ThreadState == System.Threading.ThreadState.Running)
      thread.Abort();

    return result;
  }

  private static Thread BuildThread<TResult>(Func<TResult> action)
  {
    return new Thread(p =>
    {
      ThreadResult<TResult> r = p as ThreadResult<TResult>;
      try { r.Result = action(); r.WasSuccessful = true; }
      catch (Exception) { r.WasSuccessful = false; }
    });
  }

  public class ThreadResult<TResult>
  {
    public TResult Result { get; set; }
    public bool WasSuccessful { get; set; }
  }
}
```

Usage

```
var result = TimeoutOperation.DoWithTimeout<int>(() =>
  {
    Thread.Sleep(100);
    throw new Exception();
  });
result.WasSuccessful // = false
result.Value // = 0

var result = TimeoutOperation.DoWithTimeout<int>(() =>
  {
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    return 5;
  });
result.WasSuccessful // = true
result.Value // = 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this question.  What your asking for is exactly one of the uses I intended.
[Implement C# Generic Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-generic-timeout)

WARNING: This sample uses Thread.Abort.  Follow the link to my original question to read a few warnings about that in the comments.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;

namespace Something
{
  public static class TimeoutWrapper
  {
    public static void Invoke(TimeSpan timeout, Action action)
    {
      Invoke(timeout, action, null);
    }
    public static void Invoke(TimeSpan timeout, Action action, Action abort)
    {
      Thread threadToKill = null;
      Action wrappedAction = () =>
      {
        threadToKill = Thread.CurrentThread;
        action();
      };

      IAsyncResult result = wrappedAction.BeginInvoke(null, null);
      if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeout, true))
      {
        wrappedAction.EndInvoke(result);
      }
      else
      {
        if (threadToKill != null)
        {
          try { threadToKill.Abort(); }
          catch { /* Ignore */ }
        }

        if (abort != null)
          abort();

        throw new TimeoutException();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Just run this in a loop with appropriate timeout control.

```
DateTime endAt = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(1);
Timespan timeout = new Timespan( 0, 0, 0, 5);
while( DateTime.Now < endAt )
{
    try
    {
        TimeoutWrapper.Invoke( timeout, () => DoSomething());
        break;
    } 
    catch( TimeoutException ex ) 
    { /* Do something */ }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a method that takes a lambda expression for Statement To Execute and a parameter for timeout. Inside that method execute the lambda expression inside the try / catch block and use parameter for the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

This code is wrong (infinite loop):

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(time).Milliseconds > 10000)
```

The right one is:

```
if (DateTime.Now.Subtract(time).TotalMilliseconds > 10000)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution:

```
long TIMEOUT = 60000; // 1 minute
long INTERVAL = 1000; // 1 second

System.DateTime startTime = System.DateTime.Now;    

while (check_condition())
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(INTERVAL);
    long elapsedTime = System.DateTime.Now.Millisecond - startTime.Millisecond;

    if (elapsedTime > TIMEOUT)
    {
        throw new Exception("Timeout exceeded");
    }
}
```

Comment: you could also just "break" instead of throwing an exception if you don't care to handle it.

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution I'm using, an improved version of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/715658/3873799).

```cs
public static class ExecutionExtensions
{
    public static object? InvokeWithRetry(Delegate method, TimeSpan timeout, bool exceptionOnTimeout = false, params object?[] parameters)
    {
        DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                return method.DynamicInvoke(parameters);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (DateTime.Now - startTime > timeout)
                    if (exceptionOnTimeout)
                        throw;
                    else
                        return default;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
public class SparqlReader
{
    delegate SparqlResultSet DelegateQuery(string query);

    protected SparqlRemoteEndpoint sparqlRemoteEndpoint;

    public SparqlResultSet GetResult(string query)
    {
        return ExecutionExtensions.DoOrTimeout(new DelegateQuery(sparqlRemoteEndpoint.QueryWithResultSet), new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30), parameters: query) as SparqlResultSet;
    }

    ...
}
```