# C#: meaning of statement... Action wrappedAction = () =>

Tags: c#-3.0

Saw the code [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-generic-timeout). Can any one tell me what it means?

```
    Action wrappedAction = () => 
    { 
        threadToKill = Thread.CurrentThread; 
        action(); 
    };
```

Can we write such code with .net v2.0...?

Comment: Just a note ... this would be C# 3.0 syntax, which would require .NET 3.5, however, recall C# 3.0 came with .NET 3.5 and that .NET 3.5 is actually just additional libraries that is still built on CLR v2.0.

Comment: FWIW, C# 3.0 syntax requires at least .NET 2.0 framework.  The project settings determine if it's compiled for 2.0 or 3.5 framework.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is a lambda expression, and is only available in C# 3.0+.  The C# 2.0 version of that code looks like this:

```
Action wrappedAction = delegate() 
{ 
    threadToKill = Thread.CurrentThread; 
    action(); 
};
```

Assuming you have declared the Action delegate previously.

Comment: This is syntactic sugar, not framework magic.  So, should read "...only available in C# 3.0+.  The C# 2.0 version..."

Answer (score 5):

It means that `wrapAction` is a delegate, that takes in no parameter and that executes the following code block

```
  threadToKill = Thread.CurrentThread; 
  action();
```

It's equivalent to

```
public delegate void wrapActionDel(); 

public void wrapAction()
{
      threadToKill = Thread.CurrentThread; 
      action();
}

public void CallwrapAction()
{
   wrapActionDel del = wrapAction;
   del ();
}
```

You can see that this is verbose, but `Action` is not.

And, this is only available in .Net 3.5. Don't worry, your .net 2.0 code will work seamlessly with .net 3.5, so you can just upgrade.

Comment: +1, re upgrading, it's amazing how many people don't think like this.

Comment: @Mark: Re upgrading: Remember that "getting the code to run" is only part of the upgrade process. Other parts are: Updating the deployment process (newer framework), updating the system requirements (W2k no longer supported), updating the dev environment (VS 2005 -> 2008), etc.

Comment: why are you += a delegate, it is not an event.  you would want to "new" the delegate

Comment: @CSharpAtl, both are OK. You can install Resharper and it will suggest the method I put forward.

Comment: You can do `wrapActionDel del = wrapAction;` but not `+=` and then call it as `del();`

Comment: @Heinzi - you should want to upgrade (should have already upgraded?) the development environment to 2008 for any number of reasons - not least multi-targetting - regardless of whether you are able to bring the projects up to V3.5