# How to set timeout for a line of c# code

Tags: c#, timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Set timeout to an operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265412/set-timeout-to-an-operation)

How can i set timeout for a line of code in c#.
For example
`RunThisLine(SomeMethod(Some Input), TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10))`
run `SomeMethod` with 10 second time out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that "line" of code cooperative, i.e. does it somehow support cancelling?

Comment: No, the line processing must be limited to specified time.

Answer (score 163, accepted):

You can use the [Task Parallel Library](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609.aspx). To be more exact, you can use  [`Task.Wait(TimeSpan)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd235606(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;

var task = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(input));
if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
    return task.Result;
else
    throw new Exception("Timed out");
```

Comment: It's great. The result of `SomeMethod` will be in `task.Result` variable. Thanks.

Comment: It's not necessary to use the `CancellationToken` if you just need timeout, and/or your method does not handle the token on cancelation. Wait has an overload without `token` that works just fine.

Comment: Take care guys, this _might_ change the behaviour of the app (as in my case)

Comment: this is good solution but, this is not stop function. only notify about timeout.

Comment: @BondaryukVladimir: Yep, just as the documentation for `Task.Wait` states. If [task cancellation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd997396(v=vs.110).aspx) is required, you have to use `CancellationToken`s and handle them from within your task. Do not utilize the deprecated `Thread.Abort`-method!
I've had a sample to this included earlier, but simplified it due to comments to this answer. I will edit it, in order to demonstrate how to use it, if that's whats causing confusion.

Comment: @Carsten Is it possible to have SomeMethod is some InterOP(COM) Method

Comment: @ChiragMM Sure it is, because interop libraries are also just .NET assemblies! However, you have to make sure the COM library behind your interop does support multithreading. If the called object is in an STA, then the Marhsaller will take care of syncing your requests. Otherwise the object itself needs to synchronize parallel calls, if required. But that's not a requirement of the calling code (i.e. if you call your COM objects from multiple C++ threads, you would have to do the same).

Comment: @trapicki This really depends. As `Wait` won't end the thread that executes `SomeMethod`, if you have a listener in SomeMethod, it will still listen instead of cancel out. It can also consume unecessary resource after timeout.

Comment: The snippet will still wait for 10s, even if SomeMethod responds in 2s.

Comment: @ValerianPereira: It shouldn't, according to [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.wait?view=netframework-4.8#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Wait_System_TimeSpan_) (see Remarks), it blocks until a) *the task completes successfully*, b) the task throws an exception or c) the task times out.

Comment: Rather than running `SomeMethod` on a separate thread (which might be troublesome in some applications - eg if `SomeMethod` has to access the UI thread), you could alternatively put your timeout on a separate thread like this: https://gist.github.com/derekantrican/dd358184c3ea8d26ba1cef70d31dda36

Comment: @derekantrican: Indeed this can be an option. However, instead of `System.Threading`, it should also be implemented using TPL (and [cooperative cancellation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/destroying-threads)) for newer Framework versions. Otherwise it is not compatible with .NET Core, since it calls `Thread.Abort` if the code does not time-out. In that case, you receive a `PlatformNotSupportedException`.

Answer (score 17):

You can use the IAsyncResult and Action class/interface to achieve this.

```
public void TimeoutExample()
{
    IAsyncResult result;
    Action action = () =>
    {
        // Your code here
    };

    result = action.BeginInvoke(null, null);

    if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(10000))
         Console.WriteLine("Method successful.");
    else
         Console.WriteLine("Method timed out.");
}
```

Comment: Very simple to use!! But do this also kill the other task or? (in case of timeout)

Comment: other task = action*

Answer (score 9):

I use something like this (you should add code to deal with the various fails):

```
    var response = RunTaskWithTimeout<ReturnType>(
        (Func<ReturnType>)delegate { return SomeMethod(someInput); }, 30);


    /// <summary>
    /// Generic method to run a task on a background thread with a specific timeout, if the task fails,
    /// notifies a user
    /// </summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">Return type of function</typeparam>
    /// <param name="TaskAction">Function delegate for task to perform</param>
    /// <param name="TimeoutSeconds">Time to allow before task times out</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    private T RunTaskWithTimeout<T>(Func<T> TaskAction, int TimeoutSeconds)
    {
        Task<T> backgroundTask;

        try
        {
            backgroundTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(TaskAction);
            backgroundTask.Wait(new TimeSpan(0, 0, TimeoutSeconds));
        }
        catch (AggregateException ex)
        {
            // task failed
            var failMessage = ex.Flatten().InnerException.Message);
            return default(T);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            // task failed
            var failMessage = ex.Message;
            return default(T);
        }

        if (!backgroundTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            // task timed out
            return default(T);
        }

        // task succeeded
        return backgroundTask.Result;
    }
```

Comment: Please note: This doesn't cancel the action after the timeout. I am not saying that it should do that - I am mentioning it because I think this is an important detail.

Comment: You can also do Task.CancelAfter and check for cancellation