# Xamarin : set timeout to webrequest task

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a function like :

```
public static Task<string> MakeAsyncRequest(string url, string contentType)
        {
            LogMe (TAG, url);
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.ContentType = contentType;
            request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Get;
            request.Timeout = 200000;
            request.Proxy = null;


            Task<WebResponse> task = Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                request.BeginGetResponse,
                asyncResult => request.EndGetResponse(asyncResult),
                (object)null);
            return task.ContinueWith(t => ReadStreamFromResponse(t.Result));
        }
```

So,how to set timeout for this tasK?
For example after 10 sec this task cancelled and toast say "Connection timeout"
I am a beginner in C#
Please assist.

Comment: [please check this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513650/how-to-set-timeout-for-a-line-of-c-sharp-code)

Comment: Also you might want to consider using HttpClient instead with builtin timeout.

Answer (score 0):

When you use this, the time of the function is 20000ms = 20s for timeout.

This function execute a response for the requested. Use this code to read the response.

```
private static string ReadStreamFromResponse(WebResponse response)
    {

        using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(responseStream))
        {
            //Need to return this response 
            strContent = sr.ReadToEnd();
        }
        return strContent;

    }
```

I guess this help you.

I'm working on the same code, please, ask for me if you need.

sincerily Renan costella

Answer (score -1):

> CountDownTimer counter = new CountDownTimer(1000 * 10, 0) {
>
> @Override           public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {          }
>
> @Override
>   public void onFinish() {
>
> ```
>           // finish that task
>
>     }
> ```
>
> };

call below methode before before MakeAsyncRequest(...) ;

> counter.start();