# How to set Timeout in HttpWebResponse C# Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms, http

Currently I have this code:

```
    public bool checkIfDown(string URL)
    {
        try
        {
            //Creating the HttpWebRequest
            HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://www." + URL) as HttpWebRequest;
            //Setting the Request method HEAD, you can also use GET too.
            request.Method = "HEAD";
            request.Timeout = 1000;
            //Getting the Web Response.
            HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
            //Returns TRUE if the Status code == 200                
            return (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch
        {
            //Any exception will returns false.
            return false;
        }
    }
```

which checks whether a Domain is **Up/Down**, but my problem is that the response usually take more than 10 secs to go in catch section.

For example my `string domain` is sample123121212.com, the function should return false but it took more than 10 secs.

What I want is to return `false` in much shorter time atleast 2 secs, because I need to process **atleast** `100 domains`.

Any suggestion on how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The approach that I used was from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513650/how-to-set-timeout-for-a-line-of-c-sharp-code).

```
  using System.Threading.Tasks;

  var task = Task.Run(() => SomeMethod(input));
  if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10)))
     return task.Result;
  else
     throw new Exception("Timed out");
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3603413/1600654) answer, setting the property `Proxy` to `null` can significantly reduce the response time.

Try the following:

```
request.Proxy = null;
```

before calling `GetResponse()`

Also, you can set the Property `ReadWriteTimeout` to a particular value (2000 ms?) to ensure you can limit the time required to read and write to the stream.

Comment: Sorry to say but it doesn't changed the outcome :(

Comment: I'm planning to use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13513650/how-to-set-timeout-for-a-line-of-c-sharp-code instead

Comment: @AJB using tasks is an interesting approach