# C# how to set a timer in method?

Tags: c#, timer, stopwatch

I want add a timer in the C# method. When this method execute more than 500 second. the method will throw exception. like this:

```
if(sw.ElapsedMilliseconds > timeout)
{
break;
}
```

Do you have any good idea better than StopWatch ? Except Thread. :)

Thank you very much!

Comment: What's wrong with what you're using?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set timeout to an operation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265412/set-timeout-to-an-operation)

Comment: The code you showed simply breaks out of a loop, not throws an exception as you stated. What behavior _specifically_ are you looking to achieve here? What is it about comparing the elapsed time to a timeout value is it that doesn't address your specific need?

Comment: There are 2 approaches, either method itself is measuring timeout and terminates itself (as you do it already by using `StopWatch`) or method  is *cancel-able* (in this case you can cancel it by using something what counting timeout in parallel with its execution - `Timer`, `Thread`, `Task`, etc). If method is *black box* (you can't modify it and it doesn't support cancel request), then you are talking about *terminating*. There are few possibilities to terminate running code, but none is recommended. Could you provide more details please about what is your case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Task with CancellationTokenSource

```cs
void LongMethod(CancellationToken token)
{
    for (int i=0; i<51; ++i)
    {
        token.ThrowIfCancellationRequested();
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // some sub operation
    }
}

void Run()
{
    var source = new CancellationTokenSource(50000); // 50 sec delay
    var task = new Task(() => LongMethod(source.Token), source.Token);
    task.Wait();
}
```

Comment: -1 because it's generally a bad idea to use Thread.Sleep, especially for timing. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8815895/why-is-thread-sleep-so-harmful for more info. A better solution is to use a `Timer`.

Comment: Oh, my bad. I misread your answer. Disregard my comment :) If you make a trivial edit to your post, I'll be able to rescind my downvote.

Comment: My -1 has become a +1.

Comment: Thanks all guys. I used Thread.Sleep(). Especially thanks Xcelled194. I use it to unit test, it's acceptable.