# How to timeout, or limit the waiting time for a response from an external API

Tags: asp.net-core, client, .net-standard, apiclient

I have come across this problem generally and never really resolved it, but this morning I have a specific case.

My applications integrates with the Despatch Bay Shipping API:
https://github.com/despatchbay/despatchbay-api-v15/wiki

I won't bother you with all the code, but this morning their endpoints are failing and I am getting an error on this line of my code, which requested shipping services from their API according to parcel data I send it:

```
Dim Services As dbShipping.ServiceType() = DespatchBay.Services.Get(Company, Box.ToParcel(ParcelValue:=ParcelTotal), DBRecipient)
```

Their code is also failing on their own website.

I have temporarily "overcome" this problem by wrapping the code that requires the `Services` object above in a `Try/Catch` but it takes quite a long time to actually fail.

So how do I, instead of writing:

```
Try
     Dim Services As dbShipping.ServiceType() = DespatchBay.Services.Get(Company, Box.ToParcel(ParcelValue:=ParcelTotal), DBRecipient)
Catch
    ' Do stuff it broke
End Try
```

Write something like

```
Wait for Despatch Bay:    
    Dim Services As dbShipping.ServiceType() = DespatchBay.Services.Get(Company, Box.ToParcel(ParcelValue:=ParcelTotal), DBRecipient)
But if it takes too long
    'Do stuff, it broke
End waiting for Despatch Bay
```

I only want to timeout the response from that API request, **not** my entire code block.

If it matters, I am looking for a `.NetStandard` solution, not a Framework specific one.

Answer (score 1):

I have found this Question similarly asked here:

[Set timeout to an operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265412/set-timeout-to-an-operation)

My chosen solution is:

using System.Threading.Tasks;

```
var task = Task.Run(() => obj.PerformInitTransaction());
if (task.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30)))
    return task.Result;
else
    throw new Exception("Timed out");
```

Converted to VB and expecting my function return an object, my actual code is:

```
Dim Services As dbShipping.ServiceType()
Dim ServicesTask As Task(Of dbShipping.ServiceType()) = Task.Run(Function() DespatchBay.Services.Get(Company, Box.ToParcel(ParcelValue:=ParcelTotal), DBRecipient))
If ServicesTask.Wait(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5)) Then
    Services = ServicesTask.Result
Else
    Log.Report("It took too long to get dispatch bay records so abandon", TLog.Level.Warning)
End If
```