# How set timeout on XDocument.Load(string uri)?

Tags: c#, .net, timeout, linq-to-xml

Is there a way to set a timeout on System.Linq.Xml.XDocument.Load(string uri)? Or should I use the technique described in [Implement C# Generic Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-generic-timeout)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is nothing built-in as far as I'm aware. You can fetch the XML content yourself with an instance of [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx) (which you *can* set a timeout on) and then pass the XML data directly to the `XDocument.Load` method.

Technically, the most "robust" solution would be to implement [XmlResolver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver.aspx) yourself which uses a `WebRequest` in the [GetEntity()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlresolver.getentity.aspx) implementation to do a timeout. Then create an `XmlReader` based on your `XmlResolver` and pass the `XmlReader` to `XDocument.Open`.

The reason I say that would be more "robust" is that if the XML file references *other* entities on the web server (e.g. a DTD) then you would probably want the timeout to apply for that as well and not just the initial request.