# Set timeout during connecting do directory on server

Tags: c#, wpf

I have simple application in WPF, which I connect to for example to file and I would like to set a timeout message when the server is not responding.:

I use this code:

```
XmlDocument xml = new XmlDocument();
xml.Load('//SERVER/KATALOG/file.xml");
```

Sometimes, when server is not responding, application freezes and I would like to show a message in that case.

Comment: Check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2970746/how-set-timeout-on-xdocument-loadstring-uri

Comment: You could always make the call to a web service that implements getting the XML document and set a timeout on the web service call.