# thread start stop c# WinForm

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

Background:
In C# WinForm, I use several Threads like this

```
private Thread Thread1;
Thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomething));
Thread1.Start();
```

And I want to set a timer to Stop/Kill the Thread1 every hour, and restart a new Thread1 like this:

```
Abort/Kill Thread1;
Thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomething));
Thread1.Start();
```

So How to kill the thread1 and restart a new one without Restart my Winform?

Thank you kindly for your reply. I much appreciated it

Comment: what you actually want to achieve? Might be it will help us a lot to give you answers.

Comment: Have a look at [Thread timeout in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3195030/thread-timeout-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Sounds like you want you use a timer (which fires on a different thread) rather than creating a thread

Comment: The Timer is not related to Thread, I just want to know how to terminate the thread

Answer (score 0):

You can do so by having a while loop in DoSomething that continues based on a volatile bool.  Please see Groo's answer here:

[Restarting a thread in .NET (using C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054889/restarting-a-thread-in-net-using-c)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        var i = 0;
        Action DoSomething = () => {
            while (true) {
                (++i).ToString();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        };

        Thread Thread1;
        Thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomething));
        Thread1.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Text = i.ToString();

        Thread1.Abort();
        Thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomething));
        Thread1.Start();

    }
```

I don't recommend Thread.Abort method.
When possible, design the thread what can stop safety. And use Join method.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        // the flag, to stop the thread outside.
        var needStop = false;

        var i = 0;
        Action DoSomething = () => {
            while (!needStop) {
                (++i).ToString();
                Thread.Sleep(100);
            }
        };


        Thread Thread1;
        Thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomething));
        Thread1.Start();

        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Text = i.ToString();

        // change flag to stop.
        needStop = true;
        // wait until thread stop.
        Thread1.Join();

        // start new thread.
        Thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(DoSomething));
        Thread1.Start();

        // needStop = true;
        // Thread1.Join();
    }
```