# Add 'TimeOut' parameter to 'Func<>' in C# 4.0

Tags: c#-4.0, timeout, func

Using `C# 4.0` features I want a generic wrapper for encapsulating functions and add a `TimeOut` parameter to them.

For example we have a function like:

```
T DoLengthyOperation()
```

Using `Func` we have:

```
Func<T>
```

This is good and call the function even `Sync` (`Invloke`) or `Async`(`BeginInvoke`).
Now think of a `TimeOut` to be added to this behavior and if `DoLengthyOperation()` returns in specified time we have `true` returned, otherwise `false`.

Something like:

```
FuncTimeOut<in T1, in T2, ..., out TResult, int timeOut, bool result>
```

Comment: Are you asking how to implement it or what the signature should be?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement C# Generic Timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-generic-timeout)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Implement C# Generic Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-generic-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Don't return true/false for complete.  Throw an exception.

I don't have time to implement it, but it should be possible and your basic signature would look like this:

```
T DoLengthyOperation<T>(int TimeoutInMilliseconds, Func<T> operation)
```

And you could call this method either by passing in the name of any Func<T> as an argument or define it place as a lambda expression.  Unfortunately, you'll also need to provide an overload for different kind of function you want, as there's currently no way to specify a variable number a generic type arguments.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of mixing `out` and `bool` I would instead construct a separate type to capture the return.  For example

```
struct Result<T> {
  private bool _isSuccess;
  private T _value;
  public bool IsSucces { get { return _success; } }
  public T Value { get { return _value; } }
  public Result(T value) {
    _value = value;
    _isSuccess = true;
  }
}
```

This is definitely possible to write.  The only problem is that in order to implement a timeout, it's necessary to do one of the following

1. Move the long running operation onto another thread.
2. Add cancellation support to the long running operation and signal cancellation from another thread.
3. Ingrain the notion of timeout into the operation itself and have it check for the time being expired at many points in the operation.

Which is best for you is hard to determine because we don't know enough about your scenario.  My instinct though would be to go for #2 or #3.  Having the primary code not have to switch threads is likely the least impactful change to your code.

Comment: I prefer #1 because it has less impact on encapsulated function (no change is needed). I'm not sure this is a good idea or not: Calling function asynchronously and `sleep` for `TimeOut`. After wake up check if operation has completed or not.

Comment: @Xaqron, it has no impact only if the function can be safely run on another thread.  In my experience it's very rare to have a function which was not designed for thread safety that just happens to be thread safe.