# c# - abort the execution of a method if its taking too long to run

Tags: c#, .net

How can I abort the execution of a method if its taking too long to run?

e.g.

```
string foo = DoSomethingComplex();
```

but if `DoSomethingComplex()` is taking too long (20 seconds lets say).
then just set foo to "";

Comment: Could you run DoSomethingComplex() as a thread?

Comment: Check this post for a bunch of interesting solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-generic-timeout

Comment: Aborting threads isn't recommended. If possible run the thread in a separate AppDomain.

Comment: You really ought to solve this _inside_ DoSomethingComplex().

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a new thread running your method, then:

```
thread.Start();
bool success = thread.Join(20000);
```

Join returns true if thread finished successfully before designated time. Obviously, would not abort the method (probably no way to do *that* directly), but the thread -- but it seems that would accomplish what you desired.

A simple threading code example probably would go something like below. Note I made some assumptions about signature with parameter, all this in some class, etc. For method:

```
    public string DoSomethingComplex(int param)
```

and then in the same class:

```
public delegate void Callback(string newFoo);

public void ThreadedDoSomethingComplexEnded(string newFoo)
{
    foo = newFoo;
}

private static void ThreadedDoSomethingComplex(ClassFooIsIn fooObject, int param, Callback callback)
{
    var newFoo = fooObject.DoSomethingComplex(param);
    callback(newFoo);
}
```

usage aka code in some other method in ClassFooIsIn:

```
var thread = new Thread(() => ThreadedDoSomethingComplex(this, param, ThreadedDoSomethingComplexEnded));
thread.Start();

if (!thread.Join(20000))
{
     foo = "";
}
```

Foo should be initialized before above shown usage, so in reality you could possibly skip foo = ""; line.

Answer (score 1):

Create a separate thread for DoSomethingComplex and wait for completion of the operation in the main thread:

1. create an instance of [AutoResetEvent](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.autoresetevent.aspx) and pass it to the thread that will execute DoSomethingComplex;
2. use AutoResetEvent.Set() method in DoSomethingComplex to tell the main thread about completion
3. use AutoResetEvent.WaitOne(timeout) in main thread
4. If WaitOne returned false, use [Thread.Abort()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty8d3wta.aspx) method to stop the thread if it works for too long.

Answer (score 0):

You can't *abort* the execution of a method. What you could do is to run this method on a separate thread and abort the thread if it takes too long.

Answer (score 0):

research on LiMex or Limited Execution.