# Set a timeout waiting for userinput

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-3.5

I have a C# .NET 3.5 app that prompts for a username and a PIN.  I'd like the app to automatically reset if no PIN is entered for x seconds.  If a key is pressed within x seconds, then the timer should reset to 0 and start again.  I've searched around and found various methods for doing this, using a timer, thread.wait, but I haven't found something that was an example of what I'm trying to accomplish. I think the solution will involve using multiple threads, but I've never had to do this before so I'm not sure where to start on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't need to be that clever this, unless it's a behaviour you are going to reuse a lot.
Assuming you are showing this form modally

Put a timer on your form (disabled)
enable when the form is shown.

Add keydown/keypress eventhandlers to the boxes that could have focus
In them restart the timer

If the timer event fires close the form returning a suitable DialogResult Cancel should do it.

Seeing as you reset on keypress, little point in having another thread. If you weren't resetting then M Patel's answer is the way to go, unless you want to reinvent a lot of wheels

Comment: I'll try this method.  I'm not closing the form, it remains open and I simply reset some controls buy changing visibility and text properties.

Comment: That worked perfectly, thanks!  Just a couple lines of code too! Learn something new every day

Comment: It's simple but it's maintenance intensive. For many forms or many changes to a form (think tying in an other edit box, but forgot to hook up the keypress event). Then it can become a  bit of a pain, but making something clever and reusable has it's own cost. Making teh timeout value a parameter is a worthwhile improvement.

Comment: Thankfully this is a VERY simple form.  One textbox that changes state between accepting customer id and a pin, so this is a perfect solution. I did make the timeout a parameter which is great for working out the exact timeout based on user behavior.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-sharp-generic-timeout) which uses the IAsyncResult interface and Action to do it. I myself have used it and it works like a charm. To simplify things just use it as in the example below

```
Action wrappedAction = () =>
{
    // show your input
};

IAsyncResult result = wrappedAction.BeginInvoke(null, null);

if (result.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(timeoutMilliseconds))
{
    /// the user supplied an input and closed the form
    wrappedAction.EndInvoke(result);
}
else
{
    // the code has timed out so close your input and throw error
}
```