# Set a timeout value on calling a function in .NET

Tags: .net, function, timeout, dropbox, sharpbox

Is it possible to set a timeout value when calling a function in .NET? I am using a third party component called SharpBox that loops a set of Dropbox accounts and pulls in the contents to a given folder on my server.

> Dim itemsDownload as integer = pollSingleDropboxAccount(accountID)

```
function pollSingleDropboxAccount(accountID as integer) as integer
   //Utilises Sharpbox to download the files and return the count
   //In here a connection is established using the SharpBox.dll
   //but never gets closed or throws an exception leaving the
   //function to hang indefinitely
end function
```

Sharpbox uses a HTTPWebRequest behind the scenes to contact the Dropbox API but seems to default the timeout to infinite and this value cannot be overridden. I've lodged a feature request with SharpBox but I'm looking for something we can use in the mean time as a workaround.

To circumvent this I'm wondering if we can wrap something around the call to the 'pollSingleDropboxAccount' function to give up after say 5 minutes?

Comment: Can you use the TPL from .NET 4.0+?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Implement C# Generic Timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-sharp-generic-timeout)

Comment: We are using .NET 4, so yes this is feasible. I am looking in more detail at the library now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

1) Create and run timer after the function call and start it

2) In timer's callback do whatever you need (call your function)

Read about timer on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.threading.timer.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

**EDIT:** Note, that there are at least 3 types of timer in .NET and they behave different. Some of them will fire after the timeout (every 5 minutes in your case) until you call `Stop` on them and some of them are executed only once.

Comment: Also looking into this. We're adapting the example in the MSDN article. Thanks!

Comment: @QF_Developer I'm also very interested in this topic, would you please give an example how you solve this eventually? Thanks.