# C# DirectorySecurity and DirectoryEntry Timeout Catch

Tags: c#

C# DirectorySecurity and DirectoryEntry object operations: How do I set a TIMEOUT so I can do a catch and continue with the run time operations?  The "stalls" during the GetAccessControl() and AddAccessRule() operations have been dragging the operations to a halt.

Answer (score 1):

I do not think it is possible to set a timeout on that. My solution would be to parallelize these calls.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with spinning up the GetAccessControl() and AddAccessRule() in a separate thread and aborting if it exceeds your timeout threshold.  See: [Implement C# Generic Timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/299198/implement-c-sharp-generic-timeout)