# Use .NET 5 CancellationToken to call a method that can timeout on the main thread

Tags: .net, multithreading, .net-core, async-await, cancellation-token

In .NET Fx 4 we used to use [this approach described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299273/27194) to timeout a method call. This approach relies on `Thread.Abort()` that doesn't work in .NET 5 as explained [here](https://www.infoq.com/news/2020/12/net-5-breaking-changes-2/) *"It may come as a surprise that Thread.Abort was never implemented for .NET Core"*.

What is super useful in this approach is that the called method (the one that might timeout) is executed on the **main thread**, the same thread used to execute the caller method that initiates the call. Before this call, an **async thread** is fired to wait during the timeout interval and then eventually call `Thread.Abort()` on the **main thread** that catches `ThreadAbortException` and then in the catch handler calls `Thread.ResetAbort()`.

**How can we have the same behavior with some .NET Core / .NET 5 code?**

This Microsoft doc [Cancel async tasks after a period of time](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/cancel-async-tasks-after-a-period-of-time) shows something different where the method that can timeout is called on an **async thread** and not on the **main thread**.

Answer (score 4):

`CancellationToken` is *co-operative* cancellation; if you can change the offending code to periodically check the token to see whether it should give up, then: just do that. However, you can't just add a `CancellationToken` to code and expect it to start acting (when triggered) similarly to `Thread.Abort()`; that is *very* different, in that it *actively interrupts* execution *without* requiring any co-operation from the code that is being interrupted.

Comment: No unfortunately the abortable code cannot be changed and thus cannot periodically check for CancellationToken. Unfortunately it looks like the Thread.Abort() feature is not implementable in .NET Core/.NET5, is it?

Comment: @PatrickfromNDependteam You are going to *have* to change your code to do cooperative cancellation, and really, you shouldn't be using `Thread.Abort` anyway, it has huge side-effects due to throwing random exceptions deep in the call stack. I would have thought someone like you, having coded a major .NET took, would know that.

Comment: @Charlieface sure I know all of the theory, but in practice production logs show that we are using Thread.Abort() in a safe way (thanks to some events), it doesn't provoke any random crash nor corrupted state

Comment: @Patrick suggestion: you could use a sub-process based model and kill the entire process

Comment: Thanks @MarcGravell we thought about this option but discard it so far. We concluded that investing now in (significant) dev for a co-operative cancellation makes sense in the long run, thanks

Answer (score 1):

There are two points:

First **Preemptive cancellation** implemented through `Thread.Abort() / ThreadAbortException` in .NET Fx is not possible anymore in .NET Core/.NET5. As @Marc Gravel explains **Co-operative cancellation** (where the cancellable method periodically checks if it has been cancelled) must be used instead. As a consequence scenarios where code to cancel is in a black box that doesn't accept a `CancellationToken` cannot be implemented in .NET Core.

Second it is possible to run the cancellable method on the main thread without even involving a pool thread. Here is .NET Standard code sample that works both .NET Fx and .NET Core/.NET5 platforms:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ClassLibraryNetStandard {
   static class CancellationTokenTest_OpOnMainThread {
      internal static void Go() {
         bool b = WaitFor<int>.TryCallWithTimeout(
            500.ToMilliseconds(), // timeout
            OneSecondMethod,
            out int result);
         Console.WriteLine($"OneSecondMethod() {(b ? "Executed" : "Cancelled")}");
      }
      static int OneSecondMethod(CancellationToken ct) {
         for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            Thread.Sleep(100.ToMilliseconds());
            // co-operative cancellation: periodically check if CancellationRequested
            if (ct.IsCancellationRequested) {
               throw new TaskCanceledException();
            }
         }
         return 123; // the result
      }
      static TimeSpan ToMilliseconds(this int nbMilliseconds) 
         => new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, nbMilliseconds);
   }
   static class WaitFor<TResult> {
      internal static bool TryCallWithTimeout(
            TimeSpan timeout,
            Func<CancellationToken, TResult> proc,
            out TResult result) {
         var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(timeout);
         try {
            result = proc(cts.Token);
            return true;
         } catch (TaskCanceledException) { }
         finally { cts.Dispose(); }
         result = default;
         return false;
      }
   }
}
```